# Calculating n! and x^n and proceeding the calculation

Tags: c, loops, factorial

Write a C program to calculate (x^n)/(n!) where x is a floating point number and n is an integer greater than or equal to zero.

I coded the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
    float x,p;
    int i,n,f=1;
    printf("Enter the value of x,n\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&n);
    if(n>0)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            f=f*i;
        }
        p=(float)pow(x,n)/f;
        printf("The value of p is %.3f",p);
    }

    if(n==0)
    {
        p=(float)pow(x,n)/1;
        printf("The value of p is %d",p);
    }

    getch();
}
```

But this is not running well. Where have I gone wrong?

PS: Edit 
[image]

Comment: How exactly is it not running well?

Comment: `scanf("%d %d", &x, &n)` --> `scanf("%f %d", &x, &n)`

Comment: @dragosht Ah! That's a silly mistake. My bad... Thank You

Answer (score 2):

In your question I have recognize 3 problems.

1. main problem is `scanf("%d %d",&x,&n);` should be change into `scanf("%f %d",&x,&n);`
   because `x` is `float type @dragosht has mentioned it.
2. `printf("The value of p is %d",p);` should be correct as `printf("The value of p is %f",p);` beacause `p` is also `float` type.
3. It is better to set `p = 0;` at the beginning because you did not assign value to `p` using keyboard. There for some times you will get corrupted values because of this.

Comment: `It is better to set p = 0;` Initialisation is needed only when you actually need it. There is no need here. Use the correct terminology